# Python помогите проставить пробел

Tags: python, python-3.x

Коллеги, добрый день, интересует вопрос. Написал типа простого парсера, который берет исходник, фильтрует его и сохраняет в необходимом виде.

Вот исходник как пример.

!4212345SFRUB   FIO     02/05/1961 M
V/RUB/000000           00000 RUB

Требуется что бы был такой вид.

4212345SF RUB   FIO     02/05/1961 M
42122324F RUB   FIO     02/05/1961 M

Все работает, но немного не так как надо. Проблема в том что не знаю как удалить везде ! и где номер и rub (4212345SFRUB) проставить везде пробел.
Вот так 4212345SF RUB. Понимаю что нужно регулярками, но не понимаю как.

```
import re
bands = list ()
filename = 'APIS.txt'
for line in open (filename).readlines():
    if not line.startswith(" P") and not line.startswith("-"):
        bands.append(line.strip())

print(bands)
filename = 'bands_sorted.txt'
with open (filename, 'w') as fout:
    for band in bands:
            fout.write (band + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Как Вы уже написали, что можно воспользоваться регулярными выражениями:

```
import re

text = '!4212345SFRUB FIO 02/05/1961 M'

finds = re.findall('!(\d{7})([A-Z]{2})([A-Z]{3}) ([A-Z]{3}) (\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}) ([A-Z])', text, re.IGNORECASE)
template = '{0}{1} {2} {3} {4} {5}'
for f in finds:
    print(template.format(*f))

# 4212345SF RUB FIO 02/05/1961 M
```

Ищем все совпадения с применением `re.findall()` в тексте, начинающегося с `!`, после него семь чисел, потом две буквы в интервале `A-Z` и т.д. до даты и финальной одинарной буквы. Скобками отмечаются искомые составляющие.

На выходе имеем список кортежей с найденными составляющими значений. Их все, к примеру, выводим через форматируемый шаблон.

Comment: Спасибо. Попытался ваш код соединисть со своим, но там почему то выдавал по два 10 раз одни и те же строки. Сейчас буду разбираться.